# selecting content with javascript menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have a list of divs with multiple classes. There is a menu with items wherein each item has it's own class. the div classes correspond to these classes. I'm trying to filter the display of the divs are show respective to which classes of the menu divs are selected (stored in an array)

http://jsfiddle.net/teYwu/1/

Example:

```
 menu item(s) = red;
   all divs with class 'red' are shown

 menu item(s) = red, big;
   all divs with class 'red', 'big' are shown

 menu item(s) = red, big, blue;
    no divs have all 3 classes so none are shown
```

Comment: you have two error's in your live example first one, what's filtered? second you have `});` in this version you will see the changes http://jsfiddle.net/teYwu/2/

Comment: filtered is the array to keep track of the classes of the selected classes from the p tags!

Comment: plus you have multiple divs with same ID, which is invalid HTML.